# Question on total law and independent with events A and B

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Probability that Sam studies for a test is $\dfrac{1}{4}$. If he studies, he has probability passing the exams $\dfrac{1}{2}$. If he does not study he has probability $\dfrac{1}{5}$ passing the exams. If he studies he has probability $\dfrac{1}{5}$ going on an excursion the day before exams, if he does not study he has probability going on an excursion $\dfrac{2}{3}$
Calculate the probability that Sam is going on an excursion and passing the exams.
What i have done:
Let the events A="Sam studies for the test", B="Sam passing the exams" and C="Sam going on an excursion"
$P(A)=\dfrac{1}{4}$, $P(B|A)=\dfrac{1}{2}$,$P(B|A^c)=\dfrac{1}{2}$,$P(C|A)=\dfrac{1}{5}$,$P(C|A^c)=\dfrac{2}{3}$
Total Law: $P(BC)=P(BC|A)P(A)+P(BC|A^c)P(A^c)$=$P(B|A)P(C|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(C|A^c)P(A^c)=\dfrac{5}{40}$
Total law: $P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)=\dfrac{11}{20}$
Total Law: $P(C)=P(C|A)P(A)+P(C|A^c)P(A^c)=\dfrac{11}{40}$
Are the events A and B independent ?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not independent, because studying for the test ($A$) increases the probability that he will pass the exam ($B$)

Comment: You can check this by calculating $P(A\cap B)$. If they would be independent, which they are not, this would be equal to $P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: Thanks, the total law is correct for $P(BC)=\dfrac{5}{40}$?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by $P(BC)$? Do you mean that both $B$ and $C$ are valid?

Comment: @NDewolf $BC$ is a conventional short hand for the conjunction $B\cap C$.

Comment: @Nick Your statement would be correct if "going on an excursion" and "passing the exam" were conditionally independent given whether the student studies.  This does seem a reasonable model.  (Although one may consider whether the distraction of an excursion affects performance, we a given no means of assessing any such correlation so...)